# When developing a web app, when does the changes takes effect and when do the browser uses its cache?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Its a general question, please tell me if it is not approved to be on this site and I will close it if needed.

The questions is, When I am developing a web application, Some times I only need to save the file I am working on(not even build the project) and the changes appear when i load the site. sometimes they appear only when I build the project. and sometimes they appear only when I build the project and clean the cache.

I am trying to understand the logic behind how it works.

TY.

Comment: It's general question and most probably gonna be closed because of that. I personally am still not sure when I need to buil, and when not. Things that I know (from reading and personal experience) - when you change `HTML`, `JS`, `CSS` you don't need to build, just to `ctrl+f5` the browser. When you write inside the `.cs` files generally that's when you have to buil the project. It's not complete answer, but as general rule - when you write server side code - build, when change the interface - refresh browser.

Comment: Yep thats what I tought also, but then yesterday I changed my Js file and It didnt load untill I cleaned the cache, so it confused me. ok but thx for the answer

Comment: From time to time the problem with `.JS` file not being loaded, or changes not shown in the source is something we all face. Recently I also get into such problem. I did some research and at least for `VS 2013` it's said that it won't cache `js`, `css` or stuff like that. When your `javascript` changes do not take effect you should search elsewhere. In my case I thought since I'm closing the browser it should refresh the resource when it opened again, but it turns out I still had to use `ctrl+f5` so in this particcular case, it's not likely that clearign the IDE cache solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on browser settings.
I strongly recommend set the browser not use cache.

The setting below is effect on IE and Chrome.
I hope this helps.

> **Preventing future caching issues**
>
> To reduce some potential caching issues, it's best to have Internet
>   Explorer set to request the latest version of the page rather than
>   relying on a cached copy.  To do this:
>
> 1. From the **Tools** menu choose **Internet Options**.
> 2. On the General tab, under Browsing history, click **Settings**.
> 3. Under "Check for newer versions of stored pages" make sure **"Every
>      time I visit the webpage"** is selected.
> 4. Click the **OK** button.

http://agsci.psu.edu/it/how-to/clear-internet-explorer-8-ie8-browsing-history-cache

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very vague hence difficult to answer appropriately but in any case, I believe what you are referring to is the difference between static and compiled portions of your web application.

The best answer I can give you is that if the changes you make are in code that will have to be compiled, those changes will not show in the browser until the binaries are created (which will probably only happen if you "build" your project), if the changes are in code that is interpreted (HTML, CSS, JavaScript, etc) those changes will not require compilation as the browser will be able to interpret them as long as the file has been saved.

I hope that answers your question.

Comment: Thx, thats for saving vs compiling, what about cleaning the cache?